# routes names for a resource not shown properly in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, routes, resources, laravel-5.7

using laravel 5.7, i have the following code line in routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'Admin\AdminUsersController');
```

when i list routes via : php artisan route:list i get the following:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users             | users.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@index                  | web
|        | POST      | admin/users             | users.store      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@store                  | web
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/create      | users.create     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@create                 | web
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}      | users.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@show                   | web
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/users/{user}      | users.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@update                 | web
|        | DELETE    | admin/users/{user}      | users.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@destroy                | web
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}/edit | users.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUsersController@edit                   | web
```

why routes are not named following the directory structure : `admin.users.method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel takes the last string after slash in resource routes to decide the route name. You can refer [`Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php) file's `register()` and `prefixedResource()` methods.